# MySQL LIMIT only parent JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, limit

I have a mysql table with 20 parent rows and 38 child rows.  Child rows have the column `parent_id` which is the `id` of the parent row.

Here is the query

```
  SELECT child.*,parent.title as ptitle FROM mytable parent
  LEFT JOIN mytable child on child.`parent_id`=parent.id
  ORDER by parent.id ASC
```

Now i'm trying to do pagination.  I only want 10 parent rows per page.  How do i LIMIT the results in a way it only fetches 10 parent rows but still fetches the child rows?

Also how do i LIMIT the child rows.. like only show 5 child rows per parent row?

Comment: you can't. `limit` applies to the result as a whole. You can't do `limit parent(10), child(*)` type things. You'd need to fetch only 10 parent IDs, then get all the children of those 10.

Answer (score 5):

You need to limit the rows extracted from the parent table and then to do the join.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    LIMIT 10
) parent
LEFT JOIN mytable child on child.`parent_id`=parent.id
  ORDER by parent.id ASC
```

Comment: How would i LIMIT the child rows.. like `LIMIT 5` child rows per parent row?

Comment: @user892134 You need to `LIMIT 5` rows of `mytable` of each group where group is defined by `parant_id`. Then to join this subuqery to the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the parent table to a subquery and apply the `limit` clause there:

```
  SELECT    child.*, parent.title as ptitle 
  FROM      (SELECT * 
             FROM   mytable
             LIMIT  10) parent
  LEFT JOIN mytable child on child.`parent_id`=parent.id
  ORDER by  parent.id ASC
```

Comment: How would i LIMIT the child rows.. like `LIMIT 5` child rows per parent row?