# Sorting of the sequencing belongstomany relationship does not work

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

The `post` and `user` tables created through sequencing have a **belongstomany** relationship, and a mapping table called `like` is created.

```
db.Post.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'Like', as: 'Likers' });    
db.User.belongsToMany(db.Post, { through: 'Like', as: 'Liked' });
```

Using this, I wrote the following router to sort posts by the most likes.

```
const express = require('express');
const { Sequelize, Op } = require('sequelize');

const { Post, User, Image, Comment } = require('../models');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/top', async (req, res, next) => { // loadTopPostsAPI / GET /posts/top
  try {
    const posts = await Post.findAll({
      limit: 20,
      offset: 0,                           
      // Sort posts by the most likes
      order: [[Sequelize.literal("(COUNT(`Likers->Like`.`PostId`))"), "ASC"]],      
      include: [{
        model: User, // Post author
        attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
      }, {
        model: Image, // Post image
      }, {
        model: Comment, // Post Comment
        include: [{
          model: User, // Post Comment author
          attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
        }],
      }, {
        model: User, // People who liked the post
        as: 'Likers',
        attributes: ['id'],               
      }],          
    })
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

But when I run the router, I get the following error

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
errno: 1054,
sqlState: '42S22',
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'Likers->Like.PostId' in 'order clause'",
sql: 'SELECT `Post`.*, `User`.`id` AS `User.id`, `User`.`nickname` AS `User.nickname`, `Images`.`id` AS `Images.id`, `Images`.`src` AS `Images.src`, `Images`.`createdAt` AS `Images.createdAt`, `Images`.`updatedAt` AS `Images.updatedAt`, `Images`.`PostId` AS `Images.PostId`, `Comments`.`id` AS `Comments.id`, `Comments`.`content` AS `Comments.content`, `Comments`.`createdAt` AS `Comments.createdAt`, `Comments`.`updatedAt` AS `Comments.updatedAt`, `Comments`.`UserId` AS `Comments.UserId`, `Comments`.`PostId` AS `Comments.PostId`, `Comments->User`.`id` AS `Comments.User.id`, `Comments->User`.`nickname` AS `Comments.User.nickname`, `Likers`.`id` AS `Likers.id`, `Likers->Like`.`createdAt` AS `Likers.Like.createdAt`, `Likers->Like`.`updatedAt` AS `Likers.Like.updatedAt`, `Likers->Like`.`PostId` AS `Likers.Like.PostId`, `Likers->Like`.`UserId` AS `Likers.Like.UserId` FROM (SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`desc`, `Post`.`ingredient`, `Post`.`recipes`, `Post`.`tips`, `Post`.`tags`, `Post`.`createdAt`, `Post`.`updatedAt`, `Post`.`UserId` FROM `posts` AS `Post` ORDER BY (COUNT(`Likers->Like`.`PostId`)) ASC LIMIT 0, 20) AS `Post` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `User` ON `Post`.`UserId` = `User`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `images` AS `Images` ON `Post`.`id` = `Images`.`PostId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` AS `Comments` ON `Post`.`id` = `Comments`.`PostId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `Comments->User` ON `Comments`.`UserId` = `Comments->User`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `Like` AS `Likers->Like` INNER JOIN `users` AS `Likers` ON `Likers`.`id` = `Likers->Like`.`UserId`) ON `Post`.`id` = `Likers->Like`.`PostId` ORDER BY (COUNT(`Likers->Like`.`PostId`)) ASC;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
```

How can I sort by resolving the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize tries to form Subquery by default with associations and `ORDER BY` clause is composed within the subquery. However, SQL's `ORDER BY` has to be at the top level, so many cases when you need `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET`, `LIMIT`, you need to disable the subquery by adding `subQuery: false`. This will make Sequelize to form the query with `JOIN` instead of subquery.

```
await Post.findAll({
    limit: 20,
    offset: 0,                           
    // Sort posts by the most likes
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("(COUNT(`Likers->Like`.`PostId`))"), "ASC"]],
    subQuery: false,
    ...
})
```

I bet this will make your current error go away but you have a new aggregation error, because this is trying to count full records which is disabled by MySQL by default. (ref: [mysql error "ERROR 3029 (HY000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810643/mysql-error-error-3029-hy000-expression-1-of-order-by-contains-aggregate-fu))

To fix this issue and do count Likes by Post id, add `PARTITION BY`.

```
await Post.findAll({
    limit: 20,
    offset: 0,                           
    // Sort posts by the most likes
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("COUNT(`Likers->Like`.`PostId`) OVER (PARTITION BY `Post`.`id`)"), "ASC"]],
    subQuery: false,
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, the problem I've been worrying about for a long time has been solved

Comment: When I ran the code, at first, 20 posts sorted by likes were normally imported.
But since then, I'm only fetching 4 posts instead of 20. Is there a problem with the limit and offset I set?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked. What is happening is that `limit` is limiting the whole joined table (I assume if you count the number of `Likers` in each post and it should add it up to 20.).  This has been discussed a lot in Sequelize (https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9605) but I haven't seen a solution for `belongsToMany`.  The option I can think of is to make your `limit` high and let client handle the pagination. Or you can convert this to raw SQL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450352/mysql-limit-only-parent-join).

Comment: When I changed the number of limit to 32, the 12 top posts I wanted were called (20 seemed too many, so I changed it to 12) Thanks for all the posts and answers you answered me. Thanks to you, all of my questions have been solved